# capture sql developer script output in java

Tags: java, error-handling, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

As part of my java application, I have to create oracle packages from java code. Sometimes, the package code might have issues and compilation might fail. However, I am unable to capture simple failures from java. So, i have to compile > 350 oracle packages from java, and if there are errors in the package, I need to inform the user to fix them. I have pasted oracle package and java code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE plat_test IS
    FUNCTION getmsg (
        p_empno IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2;

END plat_test;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY plat_test AS
    FUNCTION getmsg (
        p_empno IN NUMBER
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    BEG
        RETURN 'sss';
    END getmsg;

END plat_teest;
```

Compiling / running the above code in sql developer throws:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
0/0       PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/14      PLS-00201: identifier 'PLAT_TEEST' must be declared
1/14      PLS-00304: cannot compile body of 'PLAT_TEEST' without its specification
Errors: check compiler log
```

I want to create the above package in java and get the result. So that I can inform the user on the failure. In java I am not able to capture the errors and the program always succeeds.

How can I capture the output in java

The java code I have:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class NewJDBCTester {
    public static void one() {

        String s_sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY plat_test AS\n" +
                "    FUNCTION getmsg (\n" +
                "        p_empno IN NUMBER\n" +
                "    ) RETURN VARCHAR IS\n" +
                "    BEG" +
                "        RETURN 'ret_val';\n" +
                "    END getmsg;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "END plat_test\n" +
                "/";

//        String s_sql ="alter table Metric_idf from ssssssss_ssst";
//        System.out.println(" SQL Stmt: " + sql);
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:bhasoor/password@10.100.1.61:34171/ssssssssssdb");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            stmt.execute (s_sql);
            System.out.println(" SQL Executed Successfully ");
        } catch (SQLException sqe) {
            System.out.println("Error Code = " + sqe.getErrorCode());
//            sqe.
            System.out.println("SQL state = " + sqe.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Message = " + sqe.getMessage());
            System.out.println("printTrace /n");
            sqe.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        one();

    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the warnings on statement object, and that gives me the error message. stmt.getWarnings(). I am still not getting the error line numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I acheived this like this. Execute the create or replace package then get the errors from dba_errors...

Posting code here...

```
import java.sql.*;

public class NewJDBCTester {
    public static void one() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        String s_sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY plat_test AS\n" +
                "    FUNCTION getmsg (\n" +
                "        p_empno IN NUMBER\n" +
                "    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS\n" +
                "    BEGIN\n" +
//                "       RETURN 'sss';\n" +
                "    END getmsg;\n" +
                "END plat_test;\n";

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@10.100.1.61:34171/somedb");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("EXECUTING QUERY");
            rset = stmt.executeQuery(s_sql);
            rset.close();
            stmt.close();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT line, text FROM DBA_ERRORS   WHERE OWNER = 'Bhasoor'  AND NAME = 'PLAT_TEST' ORDER BY SEQUENCE desc");
            while (rset.next()) {
                System.out.println("ERROR AT LINE ::: " + rset.getString("line"));
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.println("ERROR DETAILS::: " + rset.getString("text"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqe) {
            System.out.println("Error Code = " + sqe.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("SQL state = " + sqe.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Message = " + sqe.getMessage());
            System.out.println("printTrace \n");
            sqe.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        one();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can know if an error occurs by this way:

```java
boolean result = stmt.execute(s_sql);
System.out.println(result ? " SQL Executed Successfully " : " SQL Executed with error ");
```

Then, the following query give you the error:

```sql
select * 
from ALL_ERRORS  
where owner = 'METRICSTREAM' 
and name = 'PLAT_TEST' 
--and type = 'PACKAGE BODY' 
order by sequence
```

Here, there is no `SQLException` because the compilation has been completed, but with some errors.

You should use `try-with-resource` like this to avoid memory leaks:

```java
try ( //
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.1.61:34171/pdb", "metricstream", "password"); //
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); //
) {
    boolean result = stmt.execute(s_sql);
    System.out.println(result ? " SQL Executed Successfully " : " SQL Executed with error ");
}
catch (SQLException sqe) {
    System.out.println("Error Code = " + sqe.getErrorCode());
    System.out.println("SQL state = " + sqe.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("Message = " + sqe.getMessage());
    System.out.println("printTrace /n");
    sqe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this blog from a few years ago.
You can use the libraries from Oracle SQLDeveloper or Oracle SQLcl to run scripts like you would on the command line.
https://barrymcgillin.blogspot.com/2018/04/run-your-sql-script-from-java-now.html

In your script, you can do simple sqlplus things like

```
Begin
 my stuff;
end;
/

show errors
```

You can also get the errors from the executor object after it has run.